# Database Table Schema not creating with flask sqlalchemy ORM package

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create to blog but I'm having issues creating database using **sqlite** as my database engine in which I created classes to define each table schema using an **ORM** with **flask-sqlalchemy** and also another thing I noticed was it created an empty blog.db file. I cant solve the issue im having right now. As of now this is my resort for help before using **Firebase**.

## models.py

```
from blogent import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    post = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.email}', '{self.image}', '{self.created_at}')"

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    post_title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comments', backref='posts', lazy=True)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='users', lazy=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.post_name}', '{self.post_title}', '{self.created_at}')"

class Comments(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    def __repr__(self):
      return f"Comments('{self.content}', '{self.created_at}')"
```

## init.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///blog.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '48ea69eb3539fbe7e069deee6c74d46d'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
   db.create_all()

from blogent import routes
```

Comment: I think you need to import `models.py` in `init.py`.

Comment: That would be circular import

Comment: True, I missed that.  I suspect the problem here is that when `db.create_all()` is executed, `models` hasn't been imported anywhere, so `db` doesn't know about the models and their corresponding tables.

Comment: It worked now. My solution was I created another endpoint in the routes.py to fetch data from data from the database then I requested for that endpoint from the web browser and it created the tables schema in the .db file

Comment: Please read the Flask's documentation, it's explained here how to do it properly: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions This mechanics also applies without app factory.